# Intel Compiler Intrinsics

Tags: vectorization, compiler-optimization, sse, intrinsics, icc

I have decided to play around with a trial version of Intel Compiler.
And now what I  am trying to understand if there is a situation when I need explicitly use intrinsics to improve code performance.

It seems that auto-vectorization (or , shall I say, the way how the compiler utilizes its SSE and AVX registers) when the compiler does all the job behind the scene -  works fine.

Could you, please, show me an opposite example? May be some cases that involve OpenMP? What do you think?

Comment: Assuming you mean the Intel C++ compiler, right? As opposed to the Intel Fortran compiler. :-)

Comment: Yes, the Intel C ++ compiler. That said, if you know an example with the FORTRAN compiler  I would appreciate if you share it here.

Comment: [Subtracting packed 8-bit integers in an 64-bit integer by 1 in parallel, SWAR without hardware SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/105438405) has an example of code that was written in an over-complicated way in C, leading to braindead auto-vectorization instead of a single `vpaddd` / `_mm256_add_epi8`.  https://godbolt.org/z/VAdhr_ - Clang does a *very* bad job; ICC does manage to see `vpaddb` but is only doing it for qword chunks, not doing adjacent uint64_t elements in a single XMM or YMM vector.  This is a somewhat contrived case so not posting an answer.

Comment: It's common for code with mixed element sizes to vectorize badly, e.g. code that deals with arrays of `short` or `char` and arrays of `int`, but I haven't looked at ICC specifically.  GCC doesn't handle that well, often doing full-width vector loads and then having to do lots of shuffles to unpack, instead of just using `vpmovzxbd` loads or something.

Comment: I don't think these open-ended questions are well-suited for SO. You can perhaps just browse through some highly-rated questions with `[sse]` or `[avx]` tags. For all practical purposes: Just compile your code with auto-vectorization enabled (probably also with other compilers), then look at the generated assembly and decide if you think you can do better than that (also considering if it is sufficient to get optimal results on one compiler or you want similar results on multiple compilers) -- if so, benchmark your hand-optimized code vs the compiler-generated.

Answer (score 0):

See this slides, then you will know the answer.

[https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~franzf/teaching/slides-18-645-simd.pdf](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Efranzf/teaching/slides-18-645-simd.pdf)